# Spring Data JPA Query

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entities in my Database. Entity A has primary key PK-A, Entity B has primary key PK-B, Entity C has primary key PK-C.

[image]

Entity A has 1 to many relation with Entity B and Entity B has one to many relation with Entity C

I want to query Entity C based on PK-A (which is actually the Foreign Key in Entity B) in Spring Data JPA. Is it possible?

I tried using the following:

findByTableB_FK-A

But this does not work. Any other suggestion that I can try?

Comment: JPA and its queries don't use tables. They use entities. Use a Query annotation on your method: `select c from C c where c.b.a.foo = :foo`.

Comment: @JBNizet but I want to write the query method in Spring using Spring Data JPA

Comment: @JBNizet, you're correct. These are entities. Editing the question now!

Comment: And spring-data-jpa allows annotating repository methods with Query, to specify which query they should execute. This is fundamental stuff. Read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The correct method signature is

```
TableC findByFK-BFK-A(TableA tableA);
```

but notice, the `-` is not allowed in method-names.